# Image inside Bootstrap dropdrown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been learning to use Twitter Bootstrap for the past few weeks and am finally have my first issue.  I am trying to place an image inside a dropdown-menu.

The issue:  The image displays at the correct full size in Firefox but not in chrome or safari, here are the pictures for reference as well as link to the site:
http://www.japaneselanguagefriend.com/application/login.php

[image: Firefox image]

[image: Chrome image]

If anyone can tell me what the issue is and also possibiy how to fix it, your help will bwe greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a style like

```
.dropdown-chart li img {
  max-width: none;
}
```

Currently the `max-width` from the cascade is restricting the width of your image to the inherited width of the images parent `<li>`.

Comment: Thank you! I pasted that into my bootstrap.min.css file and it worked like a charm! Thank you so much for saving me a lot of time !